# Select from a select statement from a defined value

Tags: mysql

I've the following table structure:

```
id      |name     |date
1        a         2012-01-01
2        a         2011-01-01
3        a         2010-01-01
4        a         2014-01-01
5        a         2011-01-01
```

I'd like to perform a select order by date (desc), and after select the first 3 rows from the results by a condition which would be where id = 1. So the second part of the query would be "give me the first 3 rows starting from the row whose id equals to 1"

**EDIT:**
After the first "part" the result would be:
`SELECT id, name, date FROM table ORDER BY date DESC`

```
id      |name     |date
4        a         2014-01-01
1        a         2012-01-01
2        a         2011-01-01
5        a         2011-01-01
3        a         2010-01-01
```

After the second part it should look like this (so the first 3 after the row whose id is 1):

```
id      |name     |date
2        a         2011-01-01
5        a         2011-01-01
3        a         2010-01-01
```

---

I have no any idea how could I solve it, please help me.

**EDIT:**
This is the concrete code I'd like to re-write:

```
SELECT `id`, `questions`.`userid`, `categories`.`name`, `user`.`username`, `title`,
   `details`, `date` FROM `questions`
 LEFT JOIN `user`
   ON `questions`.`userid` = `user`.`userid`
 LEFT JOIN `categories`
   ON `questions`.`categoryid` = `categories`.`categoryid`
ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: `3 records from the record`? Huh? Maybe `3 rows from the table`? `select * from yourtable where id=4 limit 3`

Comment: I've read this twice and I still don't understand what you're results should be?

Comment: why not use limit? `limit 0, 3` and after `3, 3`...
SELECT id, name, date FROM table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0, 3;

Comment: there are 2 selects, that makes it harder. So first I perform a select in order to sort the table, and then I want to filter the result and return the first 3 results starting from the specified id which would be 4

Comment: Is `date` unique? If not - how would you determine the order of the rows that have the same `date`?

Comment: No it's not unique. When my page loads, I query the first 10 rows ordered by date, and store the last's id in a variable, to specify the next query's start position. I hope you understand it, my english is really limited, sorry.

Comment: So in your example, your desired results would be what?  Rows 1, 2, and 5?

Comment: I made some edit on the question, I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: @sgeddes yes, but in the new example it would be 2, 5 and 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT   *
FROM     table
WHERE    date < (SELECT date FROM table WHERE id = 1)
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT    3
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your solution looks good, much faster than the other one, you got the point :)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't pretty because MySQL doesn't support `row_number()` or common table expressions, but it should work.  Basically, get the row number ordered by the date, then select those whose row number is greater than an arbitrary value (in this case 1).  Finally use `limit` to select the number of records you want.

```
SELECT id, name, mydate 
FROM (
  SELECT id, name, mydate, @rn:=@rn+1 rn
  FROM mytable, (select @rn:=0) t 
  ORDER BY mydate DESC
) t2
WHERE rn > (
  select rn
  from (
    SELECT id, name, mydate, @rn:=@rn+1 rn
    FROM mytable, (select @rn:=0) t 
    ORDER BY mydate DESC
  ) t2
  where id = 1
)
LIMIT 3
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/860942/2)

Comment: wow, nice. Unfortunately I cant understand it, trying to re-write it for myself but its really hard especially since I have joins in my query.

Comment: @KissKoppány -- the `@rn` variable creates a row number per row ordered by the date descending.  Using that row number, it gets the rows (by row number) for those higher than the arbitrary value you supply (in this case `where id = 1`).  Finally, it uses `limit` to return the desired number of results.  Hope this helps.

Comment: hm, okay, I think I'm closer now to understand it. But I cant imagine how could I fit this to my query, which is the following: 

SELECT `id`, `questions`.`userid`, `categories`.`name`, `user`.`username`, `title`, `details`, `date` 
  FROM `questions`
 LEFT JOIN `user`
  ON `questions`.`userid` = `user`.`userid`
 LEFT JOIN `categories`
  ON `questions`.`categoryid` = `categories`.`categoryid`
ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 10

I'd say a very big thanks to you if you could help me to modify this.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want to do... if finds the first id thats equal to 4 and then selects those out. then limit the offset to go to the next row and pull out 3

```
SELECT id, name, m_date from(
SELECT id, name, m_date, @a := id, if(@a = 4, @b := 1, @b) AS join_id
FROM test
join(SELECT @a := 0, @b := 0) t
ORDER BY m_date DESC
  ) AS tt
WHERE join_id = 1
LIMIT 1,3
```

---

```
SELECT temp.`id`, temp.`userid`, `categories`.`name`, `user`.`username`, temp.`title`,
   temp.`details`, temp.`date` FROM (
SELECT `id`, `categoryid`, `details`, `title`, `userid`, `date`, @a := id, if(@a = 11, @b := 1, @b) AS join_id
FROM `questions`
join(SELECT @a := 0, @b := 0) t
ORDER BY `date` DESC
) as temp
 LEFT JOIN `user`
   ON temp.`userid` = `user`.`userid`
 LEFT JOIN `categories`
   ON temp.`categoryid` = `categories`.`categoryid`
WHERE join_id = 1
LIMIT 1,10;
```

[SEE FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07d85/1) for clarification

Comment: Don't think this is returning the correct results.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7943f/1 -- Should return rows 2, 5 then 3.

Comment: thats because he orders it.. you can easily order the data first... fixed it

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you fit your query to mine in the original question? I'd appreciate it!

Comment: sure.. does `date` come from the questions table?

Comment: I just edited with a query that includes your stuff.. but I don't know if it'll work because I can't actually test it and i don't know which columns are in which tables. hope that helps though

Comment: Tested it, unfortunately doesn't work. I created a fiddle with my table structure, and inserted your code: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b693/22

Comment: what id are you checking for? id = 1 or categoryid = 1? i got it working but just need to know for little tweaks :D

Comment: questionid which is called id in the query so id :)

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b693/33 this is with it working... if you want to go off of `id` or `categoryid` just change where it says `@a := id` ----------- to change which id number it looks for change `if(@a = 1, ` to whatever id you are looking for.

Comment: the first query (which is the one thats supposed to be yours) is not returning anything because the if statement does not match any id. it looks for id = 1 but there is no question.id that is 1 just as a fyi

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52719/discussion-between-kiss-koppany-and-john-ruddell)